# IOUtils.toString() exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

On a web application, i use async servlet.

When i use IOUtils.toString() method, convert http inputstream to String.

But get `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null` **on production server**,

and **unable to reproduce on my local machine.**

Below is the stack trace:

```java
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:202) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:250) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:231) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:133) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:362) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:476) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:350) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:375) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.42]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2001) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Socket timeout implies either the connect timeout or the read timeout has been reached. This error is not caused by IOUtils.toString().

The connect timeout will be thrown immediately when trying to connect to a remote endpoint. if the socket is open at the remote end but no data is returned when trying to read data from the socket you will receive a read timeout.

Both the read and connect timeouts can be set although I suggest using telnet to validate the port is open at the remote end first outside of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read data from ios or android client http request, how i using telnet to validate the port?Now i only set timeout on tomcat server.xml connectionTimeout field